# Is there a way to back out of an rpm update?

Tags: rpm

Say I have a product distributed as an rpm named myproduct-2.3.1.rpm.

I produce an update to version 2.3.2. The rpm contains a script to do something, like convert a file format, that runs at the end of the install in the `%post` section of the .spec file. If the script fails, I need to undo/rollback the update back to version 2.3.1.

Is there any way to do that built into the .spec file? Will it happen automatically of the script returns an error? Or is there some command I can run in the `%post` section?